# In Katalon Studio, How to retrieve the values using the javascript executor. document.getElementsByTagName('input')[29].value

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon-recorder, katalon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYFE0.png)

I tried below code but not works.

```
a = WebUI.executeJavaScript('document.getElementsByTagName("input")[29].value', null)

Thread.sleep(5000)

System.out.println(a)
```

Comment: What do you get as result? Also, please add HTML of the page.

Comment: It looks like he found what he was looking for, via the screenshot in that link....

Answer (score 0):

There is so much wrong with this question that I don't even know where to begin...

What are you trying to accomplish by using JavaScript (this is a testing code smell, for 99% of testing cases) to fetch a `value` ?

Why not do the following:

- create a `TestObject`, preferably in the [Object Repository](https://docs.katalon.com/docs/legacy/katalon-studio-enterprise/test-design/web-test-design/web-test-objects/manage-web-test-objects), that points to the object in question.
- give that Test Object the locator. This is, by default, some xpath.

In your case, give it xpath

`(//input)[29]`

. However, I advise you come up with a more meaningful selector for it (for example, select it by some `class`, `data-*` attribute, `name`) that is easier to maintain

- use the [built-in Keyword](https://docs.katalon.com/docs/legacy/katalon-studio-enterprise/keywords/web-ui-keywords/webui-get-attribute) for getting attribute, like this:

`WebUI.getAttribute(findTestObject('[whateverYourTestObjectNameIs]'), 'value')`

- this is just good code design, but [write this to some Custom Keyword](https://docs.katalon.com/docs/legacy/katalon-studio-enterprise/extend-katalon-studio/custom-keywords/introduction-to-custom-keywords) for this util:

```
// import statements here. Ctrl + Shift + O on your keyboard to bring those in

public final class GeneralWebUIUtils {

    public static final String Value = "value";

    public static final String GetValue(TestObject to) { 
        return WebUI.getAttribute(to, this.Value);
    }
}
```

Also, why are you pausing runtime by some hard-coded time amount? That is a testing code smell. Stop it!

What exactly are you waiting on? Use the `WebUI` keywords for this thing you are waiting on, and if none of those suffice, hmu and I may have the wait method you're looking for ....

Oh, and looking at that image you linked, it looks like you solved your own question.